# How to append Img to Img in html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, tags

Hello I am trying to make status bar, which I add some image after previous image.
Let me explain it clear.

I have two image(gif). Guess white 10x10px and black 10x10px.

I use this tag `<Img src='./black.gif>` on my homepage.
and I want to put `<Img src='./white.gif>` after `<Img src='./black.gif>`.

finally it looks something like this

■□□■■□■□■

Is it possible to do using HTML? or any good idea?

---------add

thanks. Actually I can have more images, and it isn't fixed. For example, I want to append a image corresponding with the value like 1-3(green) 4-7(yellow) 8-10(red). And the data from highcharts dynamic update.

Comment: *I use this tag* which tag?

Comment: i think you should go for ajax spinner http://www.ajaxload.info

Comment: I found it with jQuery. The solution is to use "append" and wrap img with div container.

(example)

<div id="image_status"></div>

$('#image_status').append('<img src="...gif"/>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it with jQuery. The solution is to use "append" and wrap img with div container.

and

$('#image_status').append('');

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1 (preferred):

Why can't you just use the `background-repeat` property and use Photoshop to create a single image with the black and the white squares? IF you can't do this, see below for another solution.

### Solution 2:

You can wrap the images in a `div` and give them a `float: left`:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div class="image_cont">
        <img src="white.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image_cont">
        <img src="white.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image_cont{
    float: left; /* OR display: inline-block  OR  width: xx px */
}
```

[**Working Example (JSFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8xWZ/)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 If `float:left` or `inline:block` isn't used, the containers will hop to the next line. The other option is to set a width attribute. I just chose float :) Also, I floated the containers, not the images themselves. See latest edit

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I personally find it best to wrap all elements in a `div` when possible. It gives me more control over the elements on my page. Just personal preference.

Comment: thanks. Actually I can have more pictures. 3 and more and it isn't fixed. For example, I want to append a image corresponding with the value like 1-3(green) 4-7(yellow) 8-10(red). And the data from highcharts dynamic update.

Comment: @Evan thanks. I will try it. But, you understand what I asked? :) sorry unclear English.

Comment: @Evan <Img src='./black.gif><Img src='./white.gif><Img src='./red.gif>....... is this possible? how to? thanks.

Comment: @newmkka It would be *exactly* the same as I've posted, just change the images I've put there with your own :)

Comment: @newmkka Is this solved or not? If so, please close the question.

Comment: @Evan Yes it is solved and tried to close it. But I can't it because this show I need more reputation.

Comment: @newmkka Really? That's odd.

Answer (score -1):

wrap the images with a div container and assign an id to it i.e. (id) then use this css property:

```
div#id img{
display: inline-block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/LZypd/)

Comment: Thank you. But I want to add the image corresponding with some data which is from highcharts dynamic update. Do you know how to do in this case?